# Page is not refreshing on button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, html

In my project there are number of page inheriting the same masterpage and all are responding except 1 or 2 page, there is no change in code every thing is right.
I inserted breakpoint on button click button no effect.
How can i check the Problem.
Please help

Here is the code of my page

```
<%@ Page Title="Product Stock" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/admin/AdminMaster.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ProductStock.aspx.cs" Inherits="admin_ProductStock" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style3 {
            width: 259px;
        }
        .auto-style4 {
            width: 479px;
        }
        .auto-style5 {
            height: 65px;
        }
        .auto-style6 {
            width: 479px;
            height: 65px;
        }
        .auto-style7 {
            height: 74px;
        }
        .auto-style8 {
            width: 479px;
            height: 74px;
        }
        .auto-style9 {
            width: 69px;
        }
        .auto-style10 {
            height: 74px;
            width: 68px;
        }
        .auto-style11 {
            height: 65px;
            width: 68px;
        }
        .auto-style12 {
            width: 68px;
        }
        .auto-style13 {
            width: 451px;
        }
        .auto-style14 {
            width: 451px;
            height: 74px;
        }
        .auto-style15 {
            width: 451px;
            height: 65px;
        }
    </style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" runat="server" contentplaceholderid="ContentPlaceHolder1">
    <table style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="123px" ImageUrl="~/admin/images/insert.jpg" Width="158px" />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style4">
                <asp:Label ID="lblinsertion" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFF66" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" Font-Names="Euphemia" Font-Size="XX-Large" Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#009900" Text="Insert Product Stock Information"></asp:Label>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style12">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style5">
                <asp:Label ID="lblproductname" runat="server" Text="Product Name" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style6">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlprdctname" runat="server" Width="235px" ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style11">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator7" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlprdctname" ErrorMessage="Select Product Name" ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblquantity" runat="server" Text="Quantity" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style4">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtquantity" runat="server" Width="235px" ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style12">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator8" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtquantity" ErrorMessage="Enter Quantity" ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblstocktype" runat="server" Text="Stock Type" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style4">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlstocktype" runat="server" Width="235px" Height="42px" ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style12">
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator9" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlstocktype" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Stock Type" ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblstockdate" runat="server" Text="Stock Date" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style4">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtstockdate" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vg1"  Height="55px" Width="235px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style12">
                <asp:Label ID="lbldateformat" runat="server" Text="dd/mm/yy"></asp:Label>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtstockdate" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Stock Date" ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style3"></td>
            <td class="auto-style4">
                <asp:Button ID="btnInsert" runat="server" Text="Insert" Width="125px" ValidationGroup="vg1" OnClick="btnInsert_Click" />            
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="check" runat="server" Text="Lets Check" />
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style12">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <asp:Label ID="lblmsg" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" runat="server" contentplaceholderid="ContentPlaceHolder2">
    <asp:Panel ID="ViewPanel" runat="server">
      <table style="width:100%;">
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style3">
                    <asp:Image ID="Image2" runat="server" Height="100px" ImageUrl="~/admin/images/view.jpg" Width="133px" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" BackColor="Yellow" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" Font-Names="Euphemia" Font-Size="XX-Large" Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#009900" Text="View All Information"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
     <asp:GridView ID="gridview" AutoGenerateColumns="false" runat="server" style="margin-left: 0px" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" CellPadding="3" Height="238px"  BackColor="#DEBA84" BorderColor="#DEBA84" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellSpacing="2" OnRowCommand="gridview_RowCommand" OnPageIndexChanging="gridview_PageIndexChanging">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Stock ID" DataField="StockID" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Product Name" DataField="ProductID" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Quantity" DataField="Quantity" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Stock Type" DataField="StockType" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Stock Date" DataField="StockDate" />

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Delete Record">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are You Sure To Delete The Record?')" Text="Delete This Record" CommandName="del" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("StockID") %>' runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit  Record">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="update"  CommandName="upd" Text="Edit this Record" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("StockID") %>' runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
         <FooterStyle BackColor="#F7DFB5" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
         <HeaderStyle BackColor="#A55129" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
         <PagerStyle ForeColor="#8C4510" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
         <RowStyle BackColor="#FFF7E7" ForeColor="#8C4510" />
         <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#738A9C" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
         <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFF1D4" />
         <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#B95C30" />
         <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1E5CE" />
         <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#93451F" />
        </asp:GridView>

    <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
        </asp:Panel>
     <br />

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder3" Runat="Server">
 <asp:Label ID="lblupdate" runat="server" Text="Select the record to be updated" Font-Names="Segoe Print" Font-Size=20></asp:Label>

    <asp:Panel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server">

 <table style="width:100%;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Image ID="Image3" runat="server" Height="123px" ImageUrl="~/admin/images/insert.jpg" Width="158px" />
            </td>
            <td >
                <asp:Label ID="lblupdupdation" runat="server" BackColor="#FFFF66" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" Font-Names="Euphemia" Font-Size="XX-Large" Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#009900" Text="Update Product Stock Information"></asp:Label>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            </td>
            <td >&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
     <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblupdstockid" runat="server" Text="Quantity" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtupdstockid" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" Width="235px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
            <td >
                <asp:Label ID="lblupdproductname" runat="server" Text="Product Name" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td >
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlupdprdctname" runat="server" Width="235px"></asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
            <td >
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlupdprdctname" ErrorMessage="Enter Product Name"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblupdquantity" runat="server" Text="Quantity" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtupdquantity" runat="server" Width="235px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td >
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtupdquantity" ErrorMessage="Enter Quantity"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblupdstocktype" runat="server" Text="Stock Type" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td >
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlupdstocktype" runat="server" Width="235px"></asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ControlToValidate="ddlupdstocktype" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Stock Type"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblupdstockdate" runat="server" Text="Stock Date" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtupdstockdate" runat="server" ValidationGroup="vg1"  Height="16px" Width="235px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td >
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtupdstockdate" ErrorMessage="Please Enter Stock Date" ValidationGroup="vg1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td >
                <asp:Button ID="btnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" Width="125px" ValidationGroup="vg1" OnClick="btnUpdate_Click" />
            </td>
            <td >&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <asp:Label ID="lblupdmsg" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Italic="True" Font-Size="Medium"></asp:Label>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Content>
```

My Client side code for button

```
 protected void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
        int  productID, quantity;
        string stockType;
        DateTime stockDate;

        productID = int.Parse(ddlprdctname.SelectedValue);
        quantity = int.Parse(txtquantity.Text.Trim());
        stockType = ddlstocktype.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim();
        stockDate = DateTime.Parse(txtstockdate.Text.Trim());
        ProductStock prdctstock = new ProductStock();
        prdctstock.ProductID = productID;
        prdctstock.Quantity = quantity;
        prdctstock.StockType = stockType;
        prdctstock.StockDate = stockDate;
         if (new InsertAction().InsertData(prdctstock))
                {
                    lblmsg.Text = "Inserted Sucessfully";
                    ViewPanel.Visible = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    lblmsg.Text = "Please Check all the fields";
                }

            BindGridView();
            ProductInfo prdctinfo = new ProductInfo();
            if (stockType == "In")
            {
                prdctinfo.Quantity += quantity;
            }
            if (stockType == "Out")
            {
                prdctinfo.Quantity -= quantity;
            }
            }

             catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex is FormatException)
            {
                 lblmsg.Text = "Character value are not allowed";
            }
            else
            {
                lblmsg.Text = ex.Message;

            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: You need to show some code before we can help. If everything was right, you wouldn't be here :)

Comment: can you put some of uyour code here?

Comment: If you show us your code, we could help you.

Comment: remove ValidationGroup="vg1" and check again

Comment: Check the Update panel, update mode conditions and Map that button trigger event to that update panel. keep break point and this..!

Answer (score 0):

Put the breakpoint somewhere where it hits. Look at the call stack and step over to the point when you find why it is not going to the method you want to trigger. 
Can't do much without more information.
Hope this helps

Comment: This should be a comment, as it doesn't answer the question of why the page is not refreshing on button click. There is no way of knowing why at the minute, but that just means nobody can truely answer the question

Answer (score 0):

I saw few unwanted code's

1) please remove the `ValidationGroup="vg1"` in your all asp.net controls except button .

2) Don't use panel , some time the button click not working on using panel control, so please use table instead of panel .(or remove the asp:panel control )

3) and must check the button click event same as server side .

4) If you give me our server side code then i will response you !!

Comment: sir all other pages are also same , i have used panel and validationgroup="vg1"but they are working

Comment: sir i have removed all the vg1 but still the same condition